# Avoid a given road using direction APIs

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, directions, mapquest

I'm currently developing a tool for motorized bicycles based in Paris, France.

My issue is that in some cases, the APIs that I have tested will return that I have to use a road that can't be used by motorcycles (the "Boulevard Périphérique", can't be used by 50 cc engine motorcycles). In all of the APIs that I have used, the only filters available are cars, bikes and pedestrians. I also tried filtering out highways, but the road I'm talking is not considered as a highway.

Does anyone knows if there is an existing API that allows me to do such a thing ?

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the engine size limitation data in hand, you can use mustAvoidLinkIds, tryAvoidLinkIds, or routeControlPoint in the MapQuest directions api to avoid those roads.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed